# How to prove that if a graph G is disconnected and has at least one edge it's complement G'' must have a diameter of 2?

Tags: graph-theory

Not really sure how this would work. I don't understand how this would be possible without the complement violating the definition of a complement.

Comment: Where is the violation? Every graph has a  complement, where points are connected in the complement if and only if they are not connected in the original graph. Or is your definition different?

Comment: How would you prove it then?

Answer (score 2):

Start with some vertex $x$ of $G$, and denote with $A$ the set of vertices that are connected to $x$ in $G$. Set $A$ is not empty (it contains $x$) and since $G$ is disconnected, $A$ also does not contain the whole vertex set of $G$. Let $B$ be the thus non-empty set of vertices from $G$ that are not in $A$. $A$ and $B$ partition the vertex set of $G$ into two non-empty sets.

If $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, there cannot be an edge in $G$ between $a$ and $b$, as otherwise you could connect $b$ to $x$ in $G$ (via $a$). That means the complement $G''$ contains all the edges between any $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are non-empty, in $G''$ each point $a \in A$ is connected to each other point $y$ via a path of length at most 2: if $y \in B$, then directly via an edge; if $y \in A$, then via any $z \in B$: $azy$.
The same argument goes for any point in $B$. That proves that $G''$ has **diameter at most 2**.

Since $G$ contains at least one edge, the 2 endpoints of that edge are not connected by an edge in $G''$. This means $G''$ cannot have diameter 1, so it has diameter exactly two.